# Configure SpecRun in TeamCity

Tags: build, teamcity, bdd, specflow, specrun

I have some specflow test and I have configured it to Run in Teamcity using NUnit Runner. But currently

I have a requiremenet to run all the test using SpecRun Runner in TeamCity.

I am quite clueless as how to configure to run test using specrunner in Teamcity as I didnt find a option 
in the Runner dropdown in Teamcity to select SpecRun.

Can anyone please help me in giving some info on configuring specrun in Teamcity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you will have to use a generic command line step in order to run `SpecRun.exe` to run the tests. As long as you use the command line switch `/buildserver:teamcity` then SpecRun should output the correct messages to allow integration with TeamCity so that it shows the tests as passed or failed.

Answer (score 0):

Timothy, Teamcity Runner Dropdown does not provide a Specrun Option.

What can be done is write a .bat file to run runtests.cmd, i.e

"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Blah_Blah_Project\Project_Name\runtests.cmd".

Now, save this .bat file in any C drive location. Select "Command Line" from TeamCity Dropdown, click on Advanced Option. Mention the Working Directory(path to .bat file) and Command Executable (name of the bat file).

I am assuming here, you have downloaded Specrun.Specflow plugin using nuget manager in Visual Studio and configured Default.srprofile file and successfully fired the specflow testcases from command line using runtests.cmd.